# Proper way to implement console menu?

Tags: python, user-interface

Currently I have console menu with structure looking like

```
def main_menu():
    options = [option_one, option_two, option_three]
    options[input()]()  #0-2

def option_one():
    #do option1 stuff
    main_menu()

def option_two():
    #do option2 stuff
    main_menu()

def option_three():
    #do option3 stuff
    main_menu()
```

Problem is using this approach makes debugging living hell since I get nested calls to same function with every step making stacktrace longer and longer.
Is there a better way to implement such logic without calling same function (e.g. `main_menu()`) over and over?

Comment: Yeah, have `main_menu` on a loop so that it just starts over the moment another function finishes.

Comment: @RandomDavis this is not just about main menu. I need a way to navigate inside menu section without getting 20 calls just to get few things done

Comment: Okay, then show a [mre] of your situation. Because obviously your current example is inadequate.